# Error Executing Macro

Tags: sql-server, vba, ssms

I am trying to setup a Macro that calls out to SQL to execute a store procedure but keep getting is message when I run it. I can execute the Store procedure via a SQL query in SSMS. Any thoughts?

**Error:**
'Application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation.' At Line 22 Position 0

**Code**

```
Const adParamInput = &H0001 
Const adVarChar = 200
Dim strServerName
Dim strDatabase
Dim strUserName
Dim strPassword

strServerName="5.5.5.5"
strDatabase="MYDB"
strUserName="DBUSER"
strPassword="DBPASS"
strcnn="Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & strServerName & ";Database=" & strDatabase & ";Uid=" & strUsername & ";Pwd=" & strPassword & ";"
Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.open strcnn
Set Cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
' Set up the parameter for our Stored Procedure *** watch the line wrap ***
Cmd.Parameters.Append Cmd.CreateParameter("I_PartID", adVarChar, adParamInput , 30, "E N T E R    Y O U R    P A R T    I D")
Cmd.CommandText = "SP_UpdateUDF"
Cmd.Execute
```

Comment: You posted 19 lines of code. Which one is "Line 22"?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a parameter of type `adVarchar` with a length of 30, but passes a string with length 38. The error message is a little bit misleading, in fact it complains about the length.

If your Proc expect a maximum of 30 characters, shorten your string. Else you can fix your issue with

```
Const pVal = "E N T E R    Y O U R    P A R T    I D"
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("I_PartID", adVarChar, adParamInput, Len(pVal), pVal)
```

Comment: Hi FunThomas, I got it to go away by changing it from 30 to 38. Thanks for pointing that out. Now I have to figure out why the pop up box won't come up to prompt user to input data. lol

Comment: What pop up box? Is it part of the Proc (as far as I know there is not Input box in TSQL). Why not put the input box in your VBA code and pass the entered ID as Parameter?